# Single server/multiple clients in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# programming. So far, I have a single server/single client, but I need to turn it into a single server/multiple client. Here is my code:

**TankServer**

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Text;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;
     using System.Net;
     using System.Net.Sockets;
     using System.Threading;

    namespace TankServer
    {
      class Program
    {
        static Socket sck;
        static Socket acc;
        static int port = 1700;
        static IPAddress ip;
        static Thread rec;
        static string name;

        static string GetIp()
        {
            string strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
            IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
            IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
            return addr[addr.Length - 1].ToString();
        }


        static void recV()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                byte[] Buffer = new byte[255];
                int rec = acc.Receive(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, 0);
                Array.Resize(ref Buffer, rec);
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(Buffer));
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            rec = new Thread(recV);
            Console.WriteLine("Your Local Ip is : " + GetIp());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter yout name");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Host Port");
            string inputPort = Console.ReadLine();
            try { port = Convert.ToInt32(inputPort); }
            catch { port = 1700; }

            ip=IPAddress.Parse(GetIp());
            sck= new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ip, port));
            sck.Listen(0);
            acc=sck.Accept();
            rec.Start();

            while(true){
                byte[] sdata=Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<"+name+">"+Console.ReadLine());
                acc.Send(sdata,0,sdata.Length,0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TankClient**

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Net;
 using System.Net.Sockets;
 using System.Threading;

 namespace TankClient
 {
  class Program
  {
    static string name = "";
    static int port = 1700;
    static IPAddress ip;
    static Socket sck;
    static Thread rec;

    static void recV()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[255];
            int rec = sck.Receive(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, 0);
            Array.Resize(ref Buffer, rec);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(Buffer));
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        rec = new Thread(recV);
        while(true){
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the ip of the server");
        ip = IPAddress.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Port");
        string inputPort = Console.ReadLine();
        try { port = Convert.ToInt32(inputPort); }
        catch { port = 1700; }

        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sck.Connect(new IPEndPoint(ip, port));
        rec.Start();
        byte[] conmsg = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("<" + name + ">" + "Connected");
        sck.Send(conmsg, 0, conmsg.Length, 0);

        while (sck.Connected)
        {
            byte[] sdata = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("<" + name + ">"+Console.ReadLine());
            sck.Send(sdata, 0, sdata.Length, 0);
        }
    }
  }
 }
  }
```

I searched on the internet, but I really don't understand how to do it.

Comment: If you are planning to use a custom protocol, try [netmq](https://github.com/zeromq/netmq), a port of [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) to .NET. Despite the name, ZeroMQ is more about [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) than about queues.

Answer (score 2):

You need use threads to handle clients on server side.

Here you can find tutorial how to make server on threads

http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm

It's very good.

Basicly. Server is listening in while(true) loop when  connects Server creates new thread to handle communication with the client.

If you are beginner my good adivce is to use Async functions to recieve/send data to prevent UI stop responding. Function like BeginConnect, EndConnect, BeginRecieve, EndRecieve. etc.

Comment: While you can use threads that way and it's good enough for low numbers of clients, it doesn't scale very far.

Answer (score 0):

Communicating through sockets - for an example you can check:

http://ludwigstuyck.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/communicating-through-sockets/

It's like a quick start with code samples.

Comment: visual studio doesn't recognize the socketPacket variable...I created a class by default, but it still doesn't work

Comment: public class SocketPacket
{
    public System.Net.Sockets.Socket Socket { get; set; }
    public byte[] DataBuffer { get; set; }

    public SocketPacket(System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket)
    {
        Socket = socket;
        DataBuffer = new byte[1024];
    }                                   
}